# I need to show the an expectation is finite

Tags: probability

Let X and Y be nonnegative random variables with $EX^4 + EY^4 < \infty$, Show that for any $r,s \in (0, \infty)$, with $r+s=4$, $EX^rY^s <\infty$

Comment: Tonelli's theorem may be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried seeing if [Holder's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) could be used here? (At first glance, maybe with $p=4/r$, $q=4/s$)

Comment: Ok, I will have a try right now

Comment: @Clement C. Could you give me more explanation. I didn't see how Holder's Inequality can be used.

Comment: See below.${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** use [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) with $p=\frac{4}{r}$ and $q=\frac{4}{s}$. *(The idea being that the condition on the exponents, $s+r =4$, really sounds like the condition on exponents $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ of Hölder's.)*

**Detailed:**

> Set $p=\frac{4}{r}$ and $q=\frac{4}{s}$, so that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. You get $$\mathbb{E}[X^r Y^s] = \mathbb{E}[X^{\frac{4}{p}} Y^{\frac{4}{q}}] \leq \left(\mathbb{E}[X^4]\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\mathbb{E}[Y^4]\right)^{\frac{1}{q}}$$ by [Hölder's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality). But $0 \leq \mathbb{E}[X^4],\mathbb{E}[Y^4]<\infty$ by assumption, so $$ \left(\mathbb{E}[X^4]\right)^{\frac{1}{p}}\left(\mathbb{E}[Y^4]\right)^{\frac{1}{q}} < \infty.$$

**Thing left to check:** to apply Hölder's inequality, it remains to argue that indeed $p,q \in[1,\infty]$. Why is it the case?

Comment: But holder inequality is $\mathbb{E}|XY| \leq (\mathbb{E}X^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}(\mathbb{E}Y^{q})^{\frac{1}{q}}$, how can you apply it when X and Y have power larger than 1?

Comment: You apply it to the (non-negative, so no need for absolute values) random variables $X^\prime = X^r$ and $Y^\prime = Y^s$.

Comment: Got it! p q greater than one because we need $r+s \leq 4$. How can you realize we need to use Holder inequality? First I thought is Tonelli's theorem.

Comment: The condition on $s+r$ is "somewhat similar" to the sort of condition asked by Holder's inequality -- additionally, there are only that many useful tricks and inequalities involving powers of random variables. Holder's is one of them. (Put differently: I know only a handful of inequalities to use, and Holder's is pretty useful.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer.